# How to design an algorithm for leadboard system?

Tags: android, firebase, algorithm, kotlin, sorting

I'm developing a basic android app with Kotlin and Firebase. It's like flappy bird. I upload all the player data to firebase(firestore). And now I need to find an algorithm for creating a leadboard system. Basically I have highscore values made by different users at different diffuculties. I upload these values to firestore and retrieve them after in `TopPlayersActivity` And this is how layout looks, I have 3 different recyclerViews:

[image]

I made everything about adapters etc. And now I need to show the datas from Firebase. For example :

[image]

I could show highscores made in easy difficulty in a descending order but don't know how to show usernames with them. I've tried to do it with hashMap like this:

```
val userScoreMap =  hashMapOf<String,Int>()
userScoreMap.put(username,easyScore)
```

But couldn't show it with score.

Here is my full code of retrieving data and processing it:

```
 db.collection("gamevalues")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {   
                userIdfromFB = document.id
                username = document.get("username").toString()
                easyScore = document.get("easyScore").toString().toInt()
                mediumScore = document.get("mediumScore").toString().toInt()
                hardScore = document.get("hardScore").toString().toInt()
                easyArrayList.add(easyScore)
                mediumArrayList.add(mediumScore)
                hardArrayList.add(hardScore)
                easyArrayList.sortDescending()
                //val userScoreMap =  hashMapOf<String,Int>()
                //userScoreMap.put(username,easyScore) //this is what I tried to do.
        
                topEasyPlayersAdapter = TopEasyPlayersAdapter(easyArrayList) //I'm sending only scores.
                binding.easyRecyclerView.adapter = topEasyPlayersAdapter
```

**Here is code of `TopEasyPlayersAdapter`:**

```
class TopEasyPlayersAdapter(val scoreList : ArrayList<Int>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TopEasyPlayersAdapter.TopEasyPlayerHolder>() {

private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
val db = Firebase.firestore

class TopEasyPlayerHolder(val binding : TopEasyPlayersRecyclerRowBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TopEasyPlayerHolder {
    val binding = TopEasyPlayersRecyclerRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
    return TopEasyPlayerHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TopEasyPlayerHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.playerNameText.text = "${scoreList.get(position)}"
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return scoreList.size
}

}
```

**How can I show usernames with scores belong to them?**

Here is the database structure from firestore:

[image]

Edit: Added database structure.

Comment: Please update the question with the document structure that is retrieved from the database.

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Do you have to use firebase?  https://redis.io/docs/data-types/sorted-sets/ is designed for this exact use cases.

Comment: My database is on firestore so I need to use it with Firebase. But I'll check that system too. Maybe I can use both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```kotlin
easyArrayList.add(easyScore)
mediumArrayList.add(easyScore)
...
```

You're using an `int` array to keep track of all scores. Instead, use an array of [pairs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/) to hold the usernames as well.

```kotlin
easyArrayList.add(Pair(easyScore, username))
mediumArrayList.add(Pair(easyScore, username))
...
```

After sorting the array, when you access each element, you can simply do `element.first` to get the score and `element.second` to get the username.

Edit:

Simple way to sort an array of pairs:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = listOf<Pair<Int, String>>(
             Pair<Int, String>(1, "ABC"),
             Pair<Int, String>(2, "DEF"),
             Pair<Int, String>(3, "GHI"),
         )
    var pairList = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.first })).asReversed()
    println(pairList) // prints [(3, GHI), (2, DEF), (1, ABC)]
}
```

Comment: `After sorting the array` how can I sort a pair array?

Comment: I need to sort only scores. How can I do this?

Comment: @Arda edited the answer to include both points